# Find command with size and time and sorted by timestamp

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, grep, find

I have the following folder setup for example

```
A/file1.txt
B/file2.txt
B/file3.txt
.
.
.
NN/file100.txt
```

I need to recursively list them with file size, modification time and sorted by modification time recent first.

I have tried the below without size... Any pointers?

```
find . -printf "%Tc file* \n" | sort -n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -name <pattern> -printf "%T+\t%s\t%p\n" | sort
```

- %T+ - modification time (and date)
- %s - size
- %p - path of file

Comment: What do you mean by regex pattern? I do not see anything like that in the question? You mean you want to list only the files that match a particular pattern?

Comment: Updated the answer with -name